# How to create a spinner that one can select a time to countdown from

Tags: java, android, timer, spinner

I am creating an exercise app, and I searched literally everywhere to try to find how to create a spinner that would show durations of times, and when the user selects a time duration, then the selected time would appear on a countdown timer in another activity. Thanks for the help!

Comment: [These](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/) are all good examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this code helps you get what exactly you wanted

In your first activity initialize a spinner

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Declare the ui component
private Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //initialize the ui component
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    //create a collection holding your desired time with a note first, we will check that later
    // to find if the user selects a time

    ArrayList<String> timer = new ArrayList<>();
    timer.add("Select your time");
    timer.add("10");
    timer.add("20");
    timer.add("30");
    timer.add("40");

    //create a adpter for the spinner and set that to the spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, timer);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);


    // create a onItemSelectedListener to get the user input from spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //get the selected text from spinner
            String spinnerText = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();


            //if the value is not "Select your time" then send them to another activity with intent
            if (!spinnerText.contentEquals("Select your time")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CountDownActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("time", spinnerText);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}
```

and the other activity

```
public class CountDownActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_count_down);

    //initialize the ui component
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeText);

    //get the text from intent
    String timerText = getIntent().getStringExtra("time");
    Toast.makeText(CountDownActivity.this, timerText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //convert the string into integer
    int time = Integer.valueOf(timerText);

    //Initialize a CountDownTimer class with the time data from previous activity
    //which will set the text view with countDown time

    new CountDownTimer(time * 1000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //set the remaining time in the textView
            textView.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            textView.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

}

If you have any problem understanding or this doesn't fulfill your request please don't hesitate to reply.
Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thank you. I have a few questions. 1) How can I code it so the time is in minutes? 2) Can there be text in the timer values? (the debugger says otherwise) 3) is there anyway to delay the start of the timer until the user presses the button? Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1. you can take user input in minute and finally convert them into seconds in your CountDownTimer class. If you want to show the countdown in minute then use    textView.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000/60) in your CountDownTimer Class

Comment: 3. you can instantiate the CountDownTimer class in a button click listener or any other listener you want. and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with the needed values, display it inside the spinner and inform the interested class with a callback about the chosen number.
There you should implement the logic for dealing with the number.
Your question is too broad to be answered more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of Strings in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
        <item>Jupiter</item>
        <item>Saturn</item>
        <item>Uranus</item>
        <item>Neptune</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

After that, set the array to the Spinner using adapter:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Obviously, instead of planets, time.

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html).